# Watch Vue 3 global variable for changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vite, vue-composition-api

I set a provider in my `main.ts` file:

`app.provide('currentPage','test1')`

And then inject it in a component `Home.vue`:

`inject: ['currentPage'],`

I then can update it and show it in that component without a problem using `{{ currentPage }}`.

But I want another component `DeepNestedComponent.vue` to be able to edit it, and `Home.vue` to be aware of the change.

When I inject the same provider in `DeepNestedComponent.vue`, I can edit and display in the component, but `Home.vue` is not aware of the change and `{{ currentPage }}` still display 'test1'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is designed only to pass some property from grandparent component to grandchild one, your case needs a shareable state based on Vuex or a composable function, let's build a solution based on the second approach :

define the composable function :

usePagination.ts

```
import {  ref } from "vue";

const currentPage=ref('test')

export default function usePagination(){

  function setCurrentPage(val:string){
      currentPage.value=val;
 }

return {currentPage, setCurrentPage}
}
```

DeepNestedComponent.vue

```
import usePagination from './usePagination'
...
setup(){
  const { setCurrentPage} =usePagination();

  // then use setCurrentPage to update the page

}
```

Home.vue :

```
import usePagination from './usePagination'
...
setup(){
  const { currentPage} =usePagination();

  // now you could receive the changes made in the other component.
  return {
       currentPage // expose it to the template 
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I display the always updated `currentPage`  on `Home.vue` with that method?

Comment: do you mean in the template?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because it's a ref, I'm not sure how to handle, I add .value? And just out of curiosity, could I call setCurrentPage() from any lifecycle hook?

Comment: return it from the setup hook to expose it to the template as I did in the edited answer, you could use it inside the hooks in the setup function  like `onMounted`

Answer (score 1):

`provide/inject` is meant strictly for **passing** something down the hierarchy (kind of similar to dependency injection). It does not mutate/decorate the given target. This means if you provide a **string**, it will be consumed (injected) as a **string**, and a string by itself is not **reactive**.

If you want it to be reactive, you need to provide a reactive object or reference:

```jsx
<script>
  import {defineComponent, ref, provide} from 'vue';
  import Parent from "./Parent.vue";
  
  export default defineComponent({
    setup (){
      const msg = ref("Hello World");
      provide("message", msg);
      return {msg};
    },
    
    components: {
      Parent
    }
  });
</script>
```

[complete example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1):

## vue3 Reactive/Watchable Global Variables

In main.js

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
app.config.globalProperties.$currentPage = ref("Page 1");
```

Watch the variable in some file (Home.vue)

```js
<template>
    <div>{{ currentPage }}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
     return {
         currentPage: "test1"
     }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateCurrentPage()
  },
  watch: {
    '$currentPage.value':{
      handler: function () {
          this.updateCurrentPage()
      }, deep: true }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCurrentPage(){
      this.currentPage = this.$currentPage.value
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Change the variable in another (DeepNestedComponent.vue)

```js
<template>
   <div>
      <button @click="changePage()">changePage</button>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'DeepNestedComponent',
  data(){
    return {
      pageCount: 0
    }
  },
  methods:{
    changePage(){
      this.pageCount    = this.pageCount + 1
      const pageValue   = `Page ${this.pageCount}`
      this.$currentPage = pageValue
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Found this solution from ["Vue3 reactive components on globalProperties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166159/vue3-reactive-components-on-globalproperties#answer-69170205) when I was looking to set a global variable for my websites color scheme

[css variables in the root class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) are also nice for setting color schemes