# Vue3 reactive components on globalProperties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In vuejs 2 it's possible to assign components to global variables on the main app instance like this...

```js
const app = new Vue({});

Vue.use({
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$counter = new Vue({
      data: () => ({ value: 1 }),
      methods: {
        increment() { this.value++ },
      }
    });
  }
})

app.$mount('#app');
```

But when I convert that to vue3 I can't access any of the properties or methods...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.use({
  install(app) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$counter = Vue.createApp({
      data: () => ({ value: 1 }),
      methods: {
        increment() { this.value++ }
      }
    });
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

Here is an example for vue2... https://jsfiddle.net/Lg49anzh/

And here is the vue3 version... https://jsfiddle.net/Lathvj29/

So I'm wondering if and how this is still possible in vue3 or do i need to refactor all my plugins?

I tried to keep the example as simple as possible to illustrate the problem but if you need more information just let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vue.createApp()` creates an [application instance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance), which is separate from the [root component of the application](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#the-root-component).

A quick fix is to [`mount`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#mount) the application instance to get the root component:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';

app.config.globalProperties.$counter = createApp({
  data: () => ({ value: 1 }),
  methods: {
    increment() { this.value++ }
  }
}).mount(document.createElement('div'));
```

[demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/o3p2tvhb/)

However, a more idiomatic and simpler solution is to use a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html):

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

const counter = ref(1);
app.config.globalProperties.$counter = {
  value: counter,
  increment() { counter.value++ }
};
```

[demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ej29zxmf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to the question but related. Here is a simple way of sharing global vars between components.

In my main app file I added the variable $navigationProps to global scrope:

```
let app=createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$navigationProps = {mobileMenuClosed: false, closeIconHidden:false };
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Then in any component where I needed that $navigationProps to work with 2 way binding:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
    navigationProps:
      getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$navigationProps,
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleMobileMenu(event) {
      this.navigationProps.mobileMenuClosed =
        !this.navigationProps.mobileMenuClosed;
    },

    hideMobileMenu(event) {
      this.navigationProps.mobileMenuClosed = true;
    },
  },
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above technique worked for me to make global components (with only one instance in the root component). For example, components like Loaders or Alerts are good examples.

*Loader.vue*

```
...
  mounted() {
    const currentInstance = getCurrentInstance();
    if (currentInstance) {
      currentInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$loader = this;
    }
  },
...
```

*AlertMessage.vue*

```
...
  mounted() {
    const currentInstance = getCurrentInstance();
    if (currentInstance) {
      currentInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$alert = this;
    }
  },
...
```

So, in the root component of your app, you have to instance your global components, as shown:

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-app id="allPageView">
    <router-view name="allPageView" v-slot="{Component}">
      <transition :name="$router.currentRoute.name">
        <component :is="Component"/>
      </transition>
    </router-view>
    <alert-message/> //here
    <loader/> //here
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import AlertMessage from './components/Utilities/Alerts/AlertMessage.vue';
import Loader from './components/Utilities/Loaders/Loader.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { AlertMessage, Loader }
};
</script>
```

Finally, in this way you can your component in whatever other components, for example:

*Login.vue*

```
... 
async login() {
      if (await this.isFormValid(this.$refs.loginObserver as FormContext)) {
        this.$loader.activate('Logging in. . .');
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.user.userOrEmail, this.user.password, (err: Meteor.Error | any) => {
          this.$loader.deactivate();
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error in login: ', err);
            if (err.error === '403') {
              this.$alert.showAlertFull('mdi-close-circle', 'warning', err.reason,
                  '', 5000, 'center', 'bottom');
            } else {
              this.$alert.showAlertFull('mdi-close-circle', 'error', 'Incorrect credentials');
            }
            this.authError(err.error);
            this.error = true;
          } else {
            this.successLogin();
          }
        });
...
```

In this way, you can avoid importing those components in every component.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this minimal approach?

```js
import Manager from "@/Manager"; //Manager is a basic ES6 class with declared properties
import { reactive } from 'vue';
app.config.globalProperties.$manager=reactive(new Manager());
```